# Cannot GET/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) I've been trying to fix it for 3 days now

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

I wrote the code, and the site gives Cannot GET/, how can I fix this? Here is my code:

```js
import express from 'express';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { validationResult } from 'express-validator';

import { registerValidation } from "./validations/auth.js";

mongoose
    .connect('mongodb+srv://admin:wwwwww@cluster0.fjgxcgm.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
    .then(() => console.log('DB OK'))
    .catch((err ) => console.log('DB ERROR', err));

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/auth/register', registerValidation, (req, res ) => {
   const errors = validationResult(req);
   if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
       return res.status(400).json(errors.array());
   }

   res.json({
       success: true,
   });
  });

app.listen(4444, (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('SERVER OK');
});
```

[image: obnoxious screen shot]

Comment: could you please copy the full detailed error message to your question (in text)?

Comment: Please add more details, which URL responses with the 404 code? Could you show your network tab please?